# Debugging Background Processing Error from ArcPy & Geoprocessing tools?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, background-geoprocessing

When I run a script in the background or Toolbox tools I will get a Background Processing Error. The script isn't the issue because it's happened several times today. When it does crash it will produce a "fatal error" message similar to the one that will close ArcMap. It closes the background processes but ArcMap stays open and no errors show up on the result messages. I've restarted ArcMap since it happened and it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1. Take note of whether this happens for a built in script or a user created one

   1. If built in, take note of whether it is always the same one
   2. If user created, try to recall whether it has it worked before
2. Test whether you experience these fatal crashes using foreground processsing
3. If possible, test using latest version of ArcGIS for Desktop with the latest service pack
4. Try running from ArcCatalog - this has less overhead on system resources than ArcMap
5. Try running same tool/script from a fresh .mxd
6. Try running the script using different input parameters - maybe it is data specific
7. Monitor your memory usage to determine whether it is unusually high before running the script
8. If possible, reboot your machine, and try running this as the only job to maximize available resources and see if that appears to be limiting

Comment: 1-1 Built In - Truncate Table(always worked, failed several times)
1-2 Also user created and it has worked before(stopped at 280 records and has gone 20000 records before)
2 - no. but the script isn't made for foreground
3-10.2 and as far as I know yes.
4 - No I have not, not installed on the machine for some reason
5 - Yes, did that earlier today.
6 - I'm not sure what you mean by this question(still new to Arc)
7 - I can check but I believe I am the only one using the machine.

Hope this helps.